# What is a good resource to learn about Ruby's Time, Date and DateTime?

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, time

I've been trying to learn about `Time`, `Date` and `DateTime` in Ruby. Can someone recommend a good resource that teaches everything about `Time`, `Date` and `DateTime` in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best place where you can lear about Time, Date and DateTime classes in Ruby are:
 Apidock - [Ruby and Ruby on Rails APIs](http://apidock.com/)

and [Ruby on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

Thats bacause theese classes are just small part of complex language - and everything you have to do - is to read language API to learn about special classes you need.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick help about 'Date Time Format in RUBY'
  http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2255